# unexpected token .pipe in gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a simple gulpfile.js when I try to run gulp style I get an unexpected token error on the . in .pipe, why?

```
  1 var gulp = require('gulp');
  2 var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
  3 
  4 var jsFiles = ['*.js', 'src/**/*.js'];
  5 
  6 gulp.task('style', function(){
  7         gulp.src(jsFiles)
  8         .pipe(jshint())
  9         .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish',{
 10         verbose: true
 11         }));
 12 })
```

My Package.json:

```
1 {
  2   "name": "app",
  3   "version": "1.0.0",
  4   "description": "",
  5   "main": "app.js",
  6   "scripts": {
  7     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  8     "start": "node app.js"
  9   },
 10   "author": "",
 11   "license": "ISC",
 12   "dependencies": {
 13     "express": "^4.13.3"
 14   },
 15   "devDependencies": {
 16     "gulp": "^3.9.0",
 17     "gulp-jscs": "^3.0.2",
 18     "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.0",
 19     "jshint-stylish": "^2.1.0"
 20   }
 21 }
```

both gulp-jshint and jshint-stylish have been installed as well.

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace for the error in the question?

Comment: The code would be easier to read without the line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you have both `jshint` and `jshint-stylish` installed and declared as dependencies in the `package.json` file for the project.

Comment: I have the declared under dev dependencies in my package.json and have installed both

Comment: Add the `package.json` to the question.

Comment: I tried re installing jshint and jshint-stylish and now I do not have the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to require jshint-stylish in your gulp file and then use it.